# How do I use j2html without rendering everything

Tags: java, html, j2html

I am converting my html rendering code to use j2html. Whilst I like the library it is not easy for me to convert all the code in one go so sometimes I may convert the outer html to use j2html but not able to convert the inner html to j2html at the same time. So I would like j2html to be able to accept text passed to it as already rendered, but it always re-renders it so

```
System.out.println(p("<b>the bridge</b>"));
```

returns

```
<p>&lt;b&gt;the bridge&lt;/b&gt;</p>
```

is there a way I get it to output

```
<p><b>the bridge</b></p>
```

Full Test Case

```
import j2html.tags.Text;

import static j2html.TagCreator.b;
import static j2html.TagCreator.p;

public class HtmlTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(p(b("the bridge")));
        System.out.println(p("<b>the bridge</b>"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import static j2html.TagCreator.b;
import static j2html.TagCreator.p;
import static j2html.TagCreator.rawHtml;


public class HtmlTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(p(b("the bridge")));
        System.out.println(p(rawHtml("<b>the bridge</b>")));
    }

}
```

Result:

```
<p><b>the bridge</b></p>
<p><b>the bridge</b></p>
```

Comment: This maybe a route to a right answer but you have omitted it being wrapped within a paragraph so cant tell.

Comment: Never saw that, I think the issue is there is no javadoc for this project (is there ?)  so I was just relying on examples, thanks alot.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I looked into the code (TagCreator.java) it was in there. That's how I found it. I'm not sure if it is in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In j2html 1.1.0 you can disable text-escaping by writing

```
Config.textEscaper = text -> text;
```

Be careful though..